# Replacing list values with for loop

Tags: python

I want to make replace of all values that are in list(i) for a string (li) and return final string with replaced values.

Instead, my code replaces only one value at a time. Is there a way to fix this simple for loop?

```
li = str('Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!')
i = ['.', '?', '!']

for y in i:
    t = li.replace(y,'')
print(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-assign to `li` each time, kind of recursive replacement. Because for now you always go from original `li` to `t` with a different replacement letter

```
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
i = ['.', '?', '!']
for y in i:
    li = li.replace(y, '')
```

---

You can also use regex module `re` and pattern `[.?!]`

```
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
i = ['.', '?', '!']
li = re.sub("[" + "".join(i) + "]", '', li)
```

Comment: I have another question as follow up to working with that splited and further modified list. I guess I better start a new thread.

Comment: @АртёмФомичёв Yes you should ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the value of li everytime replace method is used

```
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
i = ['.', '?', '!']

for y in i:
    li = li.replace(y, '')

print(li)
```

this way the loop checks for the first string to replace then re-assigns the new li value to li and then checks for next string to replace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are replacing sub strings in `li` but assigning the returned value to `t`. In theory, `t` is always overwritten when you assigned the replaced string to `t` and `li` remains the same because you never assigned the replaced string to `li`

So change the code to this

```
li = str('Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!')
i = ['.', '?', '!']

for y in i:
    li = li.replace(y,'')
print(li)
```

Comment: @azro. I know. I just wanted to explain why does it happens so. But yours is the original and the correct one

Comment: Thank you, Sujay. It makes sense why it didn't work. I have another question. I replaced 'replace' function with 'split' to see if it works, however there was an error of list object has no attribute split. Is there a way to get around with it and use "split" function and for loop here?

Comment: @АртёмФомичёв You cannot invoke ```.split``` method on a list. The problem here is ```.split``` method converted ```li``` to lists which was reassigned to it.

Comment: I figured it out. In a string just replaced all values of i with "+".  Then split by that "+".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use filter in this case, like this:

```
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
t = ''.join(list(filter(lambda x: x not in '.?!', li)))
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this:

```
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
i = ['.', '?', '!']
t = li
for y in i:
    t = t.replace(y, '')
print(t)
```

Value of li remains as it was. There is no need to use str function.
Output:

```
Text 1 Text 2 Text 3
```